# "На самом деле", "действительно" и "в действительности" - нужно ли обособлять эти фразы?

Tags: запятые, вводные-слова

Просмотрел несколько сайтов, но на каждом даются всегда разные толкования. Одни говорят, что "действительно" обособляется запятыми только в том случае, если слово заменяется на "верно" или "так оно и есть", однако если взять "в действительности", то оно не обособляется, когда его можно употребить в значении "на самом деле", НО дело в том, что в случае замены "действительно" тем же "в самом деле", по каким-то причинам нужно обособлять, хотя "на самом деле", как я узнал, В САМОМ ДЕЛЕ, нужно отделять запятыми, так как оно является вводным словом. В общем, хочу, чтобы вы помогли мне разобраться. Пишу книгу, и, боюсь, что путаница, когда я иногда выделяют какое-то слово вводным, а когда - нет, поставит читателя в небольшой ступор

Comment: Ответы даются в ответах.

Comment: Это был комментарий, а не ответ. Общие рекомендации.

Comment: @Aer, тогда какой из ответов правильный?

Comment: Джин, это было к тому, чтобы участники не публиковали содержательных замечаний в комментариях. Комментарии нужны для уточнения смысла вопроса или каких-то других формальностей.

Comment: Это-то так, однако никаких ответов ведь ещё не дали. К чему был комментарий, я так и не понял. Может у меня не отображается что-то?

Answer (score 1):

1. Надо знать **основные группы вводных слов по их значению**: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122#pp122  § 25. Вводные слова и словосочетания

В данном случае здесь **две темы:**  оценка достоверности  сообщения и довод при рассуждении.

2. Нужно различать **парные варианты:**  (1) вводные слова и частицы (обособляются, не являются членами предложения);  (2) наречные выражения (не обособляются, входят в состав предложения).

**В САМОМ ДЕЛЕ**

1. Соответствие действительности;  исходный довод; авторское чувство (возмущение, недоумение).
   В самом деле, туман уже рассеялся.  В самом деле, стоит ли тебе напрасно мучиться?  Что он, в самом деле, строит из себя умника?
2. Коньяк в самом деле оказался хорошим. Он и в самом деле интересовался философией. Вы в самом деле здесь ни при чём?

**ДЕЙСТВИТЕЛЬНО**

1. Соответствие действительности; исходный довод;  авторское чувство (возмущение, недоумение). Действительно, на другой день к обеду все сборы были кончены.  Действительно, во-первых, прямая СD лежит в одной плоскости с прямой АВ.  Действительно, сколько можно спорить об одном и том же? На этот раз, ***действительно***, он прав.
2. Я и действительно таков, как вы говорите. Это действительно интересно. Фотохудожник сумел поймать действительно красивые подводные кадры. Писатель действительно знает свой предмет.

Comment: Здравствуйте, Шарон! Мой вопрос не видели?

Answer (score 0):

Пытаясь сформулировать разницу между вводным словом ‟действительно” и частицей ‟действительно”, я обнаружил очень простое и абсолютно всегда работающее правило:
‟действительно” всегда обособляется, когда является первым словом предложения вообще или части составного предложения (не считая союза), и никогда не обособляется, если стоит не в начале предложения или части составного предложения (не считая союза).
Ваш вопрос это три больших вопроса в одном. О каждом из этих вводных пишут статьи. Спрашивайте хотя бы про одно вводное за раз.